# Does a MySQL database run faster on Windows server or Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, database, windows-server

I was wondering if a MySQL database run faster on Windows server 2019 or on Windows 10.

Are the performance based on the operating system or just on the installed hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only significant differences are

- HDD (slower) or SSD (faster)
- Network latency (now close are the client and server)

Other things:

- CPU -- Today's CPUs don't have much range in speed.  And most queries are fast enough that a CPU speed difference is usually not noticeable
- CPU cores -- See CPU.
- RAID with hardware write cache -- Beneficial for heavy write situations.
- OS -- Only if you have very little I/O and network latency might you even be able to measure an OS speed difference.

Comment: So i suppose that have a MySQL database installed on a Server with an Intel Xeon or on a computer with a good CPU like an i7 is mostly the same, right?

Comment: @TropicalCat - Let me put it another way -- If price is an issue, go cheap now.  If your application is expected to grow, that give you time to understand which component is in the most need for upgrading.  Meanwhile, come to this site for any "slow" queries.